# Process does not start, but does start when running in VS dev server

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a WCF service that has to start a process using Process.Start() when a request comes in. however, everything works fine when I test it using the Visual Studio development server, but the process doesn't start when I run it on a IIS server.

I'm guessing it has to do with permissions/privileges etc, but I can't figure out what or where I need to give permission.

This is what I have now. help would be much appreciated

```
if (uri.StartsWith("http://"))
{
    Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo() { FileName = uri, UseShellExecute = true, Verb = "runas"});
}
```

Comment: Anything in the System Event log or any logging from the Process exe you're trying to start?

Comment: Under what useraccount is your app pool associated with your WCF service is running? make sure that account has permissions to start that process.

Comment: Also - is this exposed on the internet or just internal?  Just wondering about the security risks of starting up arbitrary processes on a server from a client.

Comment: nothing in the logs. I've tried LocalService, NetworkService, LocalSystem for app pool identities: nothing. And it's for internal use, I'm aware of the security risks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've connected my own user account (administrator account) to the WCF Service's Application Pool. It works. Thanks to Rajesh for pointing out the Application pool's useraccount.

Also, I had to remove 'Verb = "runas"'